# Windows Phone 8 URI associations and the mail client

Tags: email, windows-phone-8

I have an application that has a registered URI association (my-prefix://) as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx however I have noticed a difference between how the emulator works and how a device works.

Within the emulator I can send myself a HTML email containing a link with the above URI prefix (e.g. my-prefix://my-data).  The link appears blue and clicking it opens my app as expected.

On a Lumia 920 (accessing the same mail on the same mailbox), the link appears black (as per other text) and clicking it highlights the entire link but doesn't launch the app.  It does nothing.

Interestingly, accessing the same mail on a WP7 device (Lumia 900) does show it as a blue link, but WP7 doesn't support the URI associations so it obviously doesn't actually work.

Reading the documentation that I've found, there is nothing specific that says that this should or should not work from within an email.  The documentation states that "A URI association allows your app to automatically launch when another app launches a special URI", and various articles state that Bing Vision doesn't support them directly (although opening a web page which redirects to the URI apparently works).

My main question is: am I doing something wrong, or is this the expected behaviour?

(Unfortunately the links with the custom URI prefix aren't generated by me so can't be altered to be http with a redirect).

Craig.

Comment: After installing your app, have you rebooted your 920 as I have found that the association sometimes doesn't get picked up straight away.

Comment: Yes, just rebooted and it is still the same. Do your URI associations work via the email client?

Comment: I sent myself an email for the geo: URI and if I uninstall Geosense then the URI is black (not a hyperlink), I then install Geosense and the URI is still black, however after I reboot the phone the URI then becomes a hyperlink. Maybe you can try and reproduce it using the Geosense URI scheme so that I might be able to reproduce.

Comment: It seems there're a few things to be aware of that have come up as a result of this, [which I've blogged about](http://www.craighawker.co.uk/index.php/2013/09/windows-phone-uri-associations-emails-and-text-messages/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the "Safe HTML policy" on Exchange can lead to some URIs with "non-standard" schemes being just treated as plain text.
If this is the case and you can't control the policy on the server, the only option is to wrap in a HTTP redirect. :(

Comment: Interestingly, Paul and I just came across that. Accessing via my Gmail the links don't work, forwarding the email to him and they do.  More interesting is that adding my Gmail to the emulator and it DOES work.

Comment: Is it, perhaps, that my phone (because of the age) is accessing Gmail using Exchange protocol, but the emulator (as a new device) is accessing Gmail using SMTP/IMAP/whatever, so it can't enforce this policy?